# Unable to boot from USB Mac

Tags: macos, bootcamp, usb, startup

I am running OS X 10.9.2 on a late 2011 Macbook Pro. I created a Windows 7 install usb using bootcamp successfully but the startup screen is not recognizing the usb on reboot. Please help.

Note: I had to create a 30 GB windows partition manually as the bootcamp option for the same was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQIaDO9nR6Y&t=639s
I have used the process shown in this video for booting Ubuntu on Mac several times, I think this should work for windows as well. Give it a shot.. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Apple Support Communities thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15798098#15798098), some USB drives don't work.

> Not all USB sticks allow you to make them bootable (apparently).  I initially tried one stick = no luck, so I had this other novelty 8GB stick that looks like a little Darth Vader (I bought it mainly for its looks), however I tried to use Bootcamp setup to make this USB stick bootable and it worked!

Try with a different drive to see if that works.